# Proving Existence of Discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, continuity

I need to prove that $f:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for any positive integer $n$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$ has an infinite number of discontinuities.

I've identified that the discontinuities exist at $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for positive integers $n \ge 2$.

My first attempt included trying to use the epsilon-delta definition, however, I've figured it'd be easier to use the limit definition (if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$).

I'm just not sure how to satisfy the 'infinite' aspect of the question. I figure I need to prove the existence of one of the discontinuities and show how there exist many more of its kind?

Any hints into the right direction from here would be much appreciated.

---

**Edit:** It has been recommended I prove this using the epsilon-delta definition of continuity and do a proof by contradiction.

Thus, I claim $f$ is continuous, and for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $$|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon $$

Since $f$ is *not* actually continuous, I will contradict myself and show that the second part of the above implication fails. So, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\ge \epsilon$.

I am not sure which such $\delta>0$ will achieve this? Any suggestions on how I can work that out?

Comment: You've shown that there are discontinuities at $x = 1/n$ for any integer $n > 2$. What is the size of this set of discontinuities?

Comment: Your statement that every $x=\frac{1}{n}$ with $n \geq 2$ is a point of discontinuity is correct, even if this is partly intuitive for now and not strictly proved. You do need to prove that $f$ is discontinuous at each of those points, by working in general in terms of $n$. I would probably stick with the epsilon-delta definition as the simplest for this one, though there are certainly multiple valid ways to go about it.

Comment: @aschepler If I use the epsilon-delta definition, what would I take delta to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n >4$. Then $\frac 1 n +\frac 1 {\sqrt 2},\frac 1 n +\frac  1 {2\sqrt 2},\frac 1 n +\frac  1 {3\sqrt 2},...$ is  a sequence in $[0,1]$ converging to $\frac 1  n$. What happens to the values of $f$ at these points? [Note that $\frac 1 n +\frac 1 {m\sqrt 2}$ can never be of the  form $\frac 1 k$ for any integer $k$ in view of irrationality of $\sqrt 2$].

Comment: $f(\frac{1}{n})=1$ whereas $f$ at these points I believe converges to 0, however I'm not sure how to prove this considering its a piecewise function.

Comment: @Viv4660 This would probably be the basis for a proof by contradiction. If $f$ is continuous at $\frac{1}{n}$, then we must have for *every* sequence $x_n$ converging to $\frac{1}{n}$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(\frac{1}{n})=1$. But this particular sequence...

Comment: @aschepler So I would structure it by supposing $f$ is continuous and thus the limit definition of continuity holds, but then contradict by showing the sequence $x_n$ converges to 0. Does this show that there are *infinite* discontinuities?

Comment: @viv4660 For each fixed $n>4$ I have proved that the function is not continuous at $1/n$.

Comment: In the sequence, what is $m$? Positive integers? Is $n$ integers $\ge 2$ or $\ge 1$?

Comment: @Viv4660 I am fixing $n$ and $m$ is a varying positive integer. I am considering  sequence $x_m=\frac  1 n+\frac 1 {m\sqrt 2}$ ($m=1,2,..$) which converges to $\frac  1 n$. Since $f(x_m)=0$ for all $m$, $x_m \to \frac 1 n$ as $m \to \infty$ and  and $f(\frac  1 n)=1$ we see that $f$ is not continuous at $\frac  1 n$. This is true for all $n >4$ so there are infinitely many points where $f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=1/n$ where $n$ is some specific positive integer. Then $f(a) =1$ and further every neighborhood of $a$ contains points $x$ not of the form $1/n$ (prove this) so that $f(x) =0$ and thus $|f(x) - f(a) |=1$ for some points in every neighborhood of $a$. Thus the condition of continuity can not be satisfied for $\epsilon<1$ and $f$ is discontinuous at $a$.

---

You should also understand that not every proof in analysis is difficult. A major part of the difficulty is the unnecessary use of symbolism / formalism in proofs (some instructors insist on these and are part of the problem). Move past that and write your arguments in natural language with bare mimimum of math symbols and you will see that the difficulty of proofs is mostly apparent / superficial.

Also if a proof is difficult there are chances that the textbooks will offer it or at least give hints.

Comment: Okay thank you. I don't, however, understand what you mean by a neighborhood of $a$?

Comment: @Viv4660:  neighborhood of $a$ is any open interval containing $a$. Definition of continuity: for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a neighborhood $I$ of $a$ such that $|f(x) - f(a) |<\epsilon $ for all $x\in I$.

Comment: So, a neighborhood of $a$ is $I=(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n-1})$. How does this generate $f(x)=0$? Since $n$ is a positive integer, doesn't $f(\frac{1}{n+1})=1=f(\frac{1}{n-1})$?

Comment: @Viv4660: Perhaps you can see that there are other points in this interval which are not of the form $1/k$ and at these points $f$ is $0$. Read my answer again. Continuity requires consistent behavior in whole of that neighborhood and not just at few points. Even if there is one troublesome point in the neighborhood continuity is destroyed. Read the definition of continuity again.